# Запуск bash-команды в Python, нужно приостановить скрипт для ввода пароля

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, bash, subprocess

Нужно выполнить bash-команду `su username` в Linux (скрипт устанавливает базу PostgreSQL). Но я не знаю, как можно прервать выполнение (дождаться ввода пароля в терминал для пользователя PostgreSQL) в Python 3.

```
cmd = 'su postgres'
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE                                                                              
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
#вот здесь команда su должна просить ввести пароль 
print(p.stdout.read())

print("...connect to postgres...")
psql = os.popen("psql --username=postgres")
dblist = os.popen("psql --username=postgres --list") #введите сюда код
```

вот что сейчас в терминале:

```
b'su: \xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c\xd1\x81\xd1\x8f \xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7 \xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\n'
...connect to postgres...
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
...create doxyCraft database...
nofx@nofx:~/doxyCraft$ psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Comment: Что вы хотите добиться вызовом `su` в вашем Питон-скрипте? Пароль можно передать, используя pexpect, но не следует su здесь вызывать.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Python

Comment: sudo -u postgres psql - ок, вот эту команду нужно выполнить.Это вход в утилиту psql, в которой потом нужно выполнить  следующую: ALTER USER postgres password ''postgres' , потом еще кое-какие и выйти (\q) Я хочу написать скрипт, который создает базу, и хочу это сделать именно скриптом с помощью psql.  (пруф - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres

Comment: собственно вопрос - как (а можно ли?) зайти в psql через python

Comment: если вы `sudo -u postgres psql` + ALTER.. хотите выполнить, то это уже другой вопрос (отредактируйте текущую версию—не помещайте в комментарии информацию, необходимую для ответа). Это отличается от запуска отдельно команд `su postgress`, `psql` вне баша. Как вы хотите пароль для sudo вводить? Явно упомяните, что не можете `psql --host=localhost --username=postgres` использовать, потому что пароля у DB пользователя postgres нет. Упомяните что `pg_hba.conf` peer у вас содержит для локальных (unix socket) соединений.